# The phrase “in duplicate”

Tags: grammar, usage, phrases, formality

What does the following statement mean ?

Admit card should be submitted in **DUPLICATE**.

a) 1 original & 1 photocopy.

b) Both originals.

c) Both photocopies.

Comment: How can you have two "originals"?

Comment: I think this is a matter of context. I would assume two photocopies. In duplicate just means two copies but in the sense that the original and a copy would still be in duplicate. You should probably ask whoever sent you the request exactly what they require as I'm not sure this is a case of language. For that reason I'm flagging as off topic.

Comment: It is ambiguous. It just means there should be two cards. Whether or not one or both are reproductions or individually generated is not stated—nor is it possible to determine.

Comment: This is also on the ELU stack: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/506961/the-phrase-in-duplicate

Comment: Please [edit] your question.  What is an "Admit card"? Who is asking you to submit something? Have you looked up "in duplicate" in a dictionary?  Is there any extra context that could help.  Otherwise this question is unclear and will be closed.